# CXF and Spring @Configurable issue

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf, configurable

I am currently fronting issues mixing a CXF web service with Spring **@Configurable** annotation.

From one side I have my CXF web service fully working and configured like this :

```
<import resource="classpath:some-other-context.xml" />

<jaxws:server id="Init"
        serviceClass="package.to.my.ServiceInterface"
        address="/">
        <jaxws:serviceBean>
            <bean class="package.to.my.BADematInitImpl">
            </bean>
        </jaxws:serviceBean>
</jaxws:server>

<context:spring-configured />
```

And in my **some-other-context.xml** is my Spring configuration containing the following Bean's :

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class MyConfigurable {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private A a;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private B b;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private C c;

...

}
```

But when I try to create a new instance of MyConfigurable bean into my service, I get a **NullPointerException** due to the null valued supposed-autowired A,B and C objects.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are A, B, C beans being created at all? Have you used <context:annotation-config> or <context:component-scan> or any other way of generating the beans?

Comment: Yes they are, because when I get the Spring context **programatically**, I can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the problem.

I needed to add this configuration into my third-part application XML files :

```
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

... and add this argument to my **jvm launch command line**  :

```
-javaagent:"path\to\my\spring-agent.jar"
```

And it just works like a charm.

I understand that this is because Spring needs at some point to have an entity managing its AOP part so that the dependencies are well injected. It would be interesting if someone had further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

[@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) is a marker used by the `AOP` load-time-weaving stuff. I assume you are not using any AOP, because there is nothing mentioned about it in your question. Second thing: you don't have to use `required=true` in your `@Autowired` annotation as `true` is the default value of `required`. I would suggest you to change your code like this:

Add these to elements in your spring configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.pckg.toscan"/>
```

Documentation says:

> Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be
>   auto-registered as  Spring beans. By default, the Spring-provided
>   @Component, @Repository,  @Service, and @Controller stereotypes will
>   be detected.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Documentation says:

> Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's
>   @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @PostConstruct,
>   @PreDestroy and @Resource (if available), JAX-WS's @WebServiceRef (if
>   available), EJB3's @EJB (if available), and JPA's @PersistenceContext
>   and @PersistenceUnit (if available). Alternatively, you may choose to
>   activate the individual BeanPostProcessors for those annotations.

So changing your code to:

```
@Component
public class MyConfigurable {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;

...

}
```

Everything should work just fine.

Comment: Hi Paulius, thank you for your answer. I already set the XML configuration you mentionned above, and changing the MyConfigurable class's annotation from \@Configurable to \@Component didn't do the trick.